# User notification in SAPUI5 using AMC channels

Tags: sapui5, abap, channel, apc

Managed to get a start with APC Channels, connect from a small sample SAPUI5 app and get messages back, so far so good. Exercise now becomes more interesting, I want to do AMC, send a message to my channel for forwarding to other users who run another instance of the same SAPUI5 app and each of these users receiving only their own messages based on the SAP User ID (that can be part of the message). Been through this really good stuff below:

[ABAP Channels Part 3: Collaboration Scenario Using ABAP Messaging and ABAP Push Channel](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/04/14/abap-channels-part-3-collaboration-scenario-using-abap-messaging-and-abap-push-channels/)

[ABAP Push / Messaging Channel and SAPUI5 Demo Application](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/09/07/abap-push-channel-messaging-channel-and-sapui5-demo-application/)

If I got things right reading these two, I can combine APC and AMC channels and consume messages I send to the AMC by using WebSocket class methods in SAPUI5. What I don't get is how I can redirect the result to another user. I was thinking that maybe this can be done by using dedicated channels per user (as written above, talking about internal application) in the AMC channel list.

a) is the above assumption right?

b) Can this be done?

c) If the above can be done, can I go even further by (I have no idea how to do that) retrieving client browser sessions for the user (in case there are more than one) and send the message only to one of them?